How do I set the Scikit Lean MinMaxScaler 'clip' attribute to match older version?
I am picking up an old project in a new python environment and cannot load my old scaler objects with the newer version of scikit learn (1.2.*). I am having a real tough time downgrading back down to 0.23.1 which is where I think the compatibility issues goes away. I'm hacking together a solution by changing the scikit_learn base.py file to automatically set the clip attribute to a boolean to resolve the issue, but I was hoping to retain the original functionality. I was assuming to just set it to False, but can anyone confirm if that how the older version functioned?

Not exactly the answer you're looking for, but may I suggest making a virtual env with compatible versions of the libraries instead? I've been through some lib version issue myself and keeping different env for different projects or use case really helps
